# ¿Cómo puedo cambiarle el color al texto de un JOptionPane?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero cambiar el color del texto de un `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` a verde.

El código que tengo es:

```java
if (this.JcbBecado.isSelected()) {
    UIManager UI = new UIManager(); // clase para modificar  JOptionPane
    UIManager.put("Button.foreground", Color.GREEN);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Si tiene beca", "Becas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
else if (!(this.JcbBecado.isSelected())) {
    UIManager UI = new UIManager(); // clase para modificar  JOptionPane
    UI.put("Button.foreground", new java.awt.Color(74, 157, 206));
    UIManager.put("Button.foreground", Color.RED);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No tiene beca", "Becas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Busco alguna forma de que mi

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Si tiene beca", "Becas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`

cambie el color de la fuente del texto que dice "Si tiene beca" de negro a verde.

Comment: Soy nuevo acá y aun me cuesta, pero lo que intento es colocar el texto o el foreground de un JOptionMessageDialog se cambie a verde, mira:

Comment: creo que se coloca así

Comment: así?, creo que se entiende mejor, no?

Comment: Entonces lo que querés es cambiar el color _del texto_, no del JOptionPane en sí.

Comment: si, no he encontrado manera de hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo encontré una pagina de un foro donde tenían este método ver el "solución" de la publicación

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta (el contenido relevante del enlace, no el enlace en sí), y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. No olvides que el formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_.

Comment: no entendí lo del (contenido relevante).

Comment: Hace referencia a que, algunas veces, en la respuesta agregan solo el enlace (_link_) de donde obtuvieron la respuesta, y no el contenido de tal enlace. Esto es: si el _link_ llega a romperse, otros usuarios más adelante no tendrán acceso a esa información. En resumen: lo que habías colocado en tu edición de pregunta, debes moverlo a una respuesta (ya lo hiciste, de hecho.)

Answer (score 2):

Para esa personalización solo usando java ,puedes hacerlo con `OptionPane.messageForeground`

Ejemplo:

```
  UIManager UI=new UIManager();
//opcional si qusieras cambiar el tamaño de la fuente
  UI.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
//puedes aplicar Color.GREEN no hay problema
  UI.put("OptionPane.messageForeground", Color.decode("#008F39"));
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Si tiene beca", "Becas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar a tu código lo siguiente:

```
if (this.JcbBecado.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html><p style=\"color:green\">Si posee beca</p></html>", "Becas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } else if (!(this.JcbBecado.isSelected())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html><p style=\"color:red\">No posee beca</p></html>", "Becas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

y seleccionar el color en || "color:red" ||

Comment: `color:green` más bien (¡según lo que dice tu pregunta!) No olvides mencionar que se debe usar HTML para realizar tal modificación.